# Unable to locate package ros-indigo-moveit-full

Tags: moveit, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use ros-planning/moveit pkg.Because it includes moveit_kinematics.But After I run "sudo apt-get remove ros-indigo-moveit-full",I can't use moveit.When I run "sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit-full" again,It appeared "Unable to locate package ros-indigo-moveit-full" .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251168/unable-to-locate-package-ros-indigo-moveit-full/) by [Lileping](https://answers.ros.org/users/28761/lileping/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2017-01-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Indeed the [installation tutorial for MoveIt! Indigo](http://moveit.ros.org/install/) is outdated. Thank you for catching that.

`ros-indigo-moveit-full` was recently removed for all ROS Indigo/Jade/Kinetic. From the next release of Indigo, which is [planned soon](https://discourse.ros.org/t/preparing-for-indigo-sync-2016-12-21/1004/3), you'll be able to install `ros-indigo-moveit` that includes `moveit_kinematics`.

If you're really in hurry so that you can't wait for another few days, you can already install them from [Shadow Repository](http://wiki.ros.org/ShadowRepository).

---

UPDATE: Opened a [PR](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit.ros.org/pull/113) to update the [installation tutorial](http://moveit.ros.org/install/).

---

UPDATE 20170105 MoveIt! maintainers realized that removing `ros-indigo-moveit-full` broke existing usecases. So it's [released back again](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/13535) and will become available on shadow repo soon and on official public repo at the next public sync (the one that was like [this announcement](https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-packages-for-indigo-2016-12-28/1039/2)).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lileping](https://answers.ros.org/users/28761/lileping/) on 2017-01-03**:
Thanks a lot.I will wait for it. I am hurry to use moveit to control real UR5.The universal robot pkg needs moveit_kinematics.

**Comment by [F4bich](https://answers.ros.org/users/27705/f4bich/) on 2017-01-25**:
Currently I can't run `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit` nor `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit-full`. I tested it on multiple mashines.
Is this still a problem with the official public repo or is it something on my side?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-01-28**:
Looking at the [package status on buildfarm](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_indigo_default.html?q=moveit&s=1), `moveit` seems released without issues. `moveit_full` will become available on the next public release (watch [this thread](https://goo.gl/hzdfbn) or similar).

**Comment by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on 2017-01-29**:
@F4bich, I have the same problem. `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit` is not being located.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-01-29**:
@F4bich @bhavyadoshi26 I've opened [a ticket](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/431) for discussing the issue more. Please consider providing more info there.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you setup your sources list correctly? Is it only the ros-indigo-moveit-full package or also other ros-indigo packages.
Did you try to when getting sources again? http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu

---

Originally posted by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) with karma: 171 on 2017-01-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lileping](https://answers.ros.org/users/28761/lileping/) on 2017-01-03**:
Thanks a lot .I haved tried sourced again. In ~/.bashrc file,the last line is "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash". But I still can't use move_group.launch .and "sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit-full", Unable to locate package ros-indigo-moveit-full.

**Comment by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on 2017-01-03**:
Did you also update rosdep and what does your pc find when you "sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-" tab tab?

**Comment by [Lileping](https://answers.ros.org/users/28761/lileping/) on 2017-01-03**:
I have done "rosdep update and sudo apt-get update".as said [here](http://moveit.ros.org/install/source/). And created an workspace named "ws_moveit".Then I can use move_group.launch But when I run a moveit_ik demo,it said "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MoveGroupInterface'".

**Comment by [Lileping](https://answers.ros.org/users/28761/lileping/) on 2017-01-03**:
When I run "sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit-"tab tab ,It didn't show ros-indigo-moveit-full, just appeared ros-indigo-moveit and others

**Comment by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on 2017-01-03**:
It's probably what 130s is saying

**Comment by [Lileping](https://answers.ros.org/users/28761/lileping/) on 2017-01-03**:
I agree with you